# Align within an (fl)align environment

Tags: align, arrays, eqnarray, flalign

I have a centered list of equations, and I'd like each of the equations to begin at the same margin from the left, then to have the equality signs start at the same margin, etc., whilst keeping the list itself centered around the middle of the page.
align does most of this, except that align centers the left side of the equation towards the equality sign:

```
\begin{align*}
\text{blablabla} &= \text{blabla} \\
\text{bla} &=  \text{bla}
\text{b} &=  \text{bla}
\end{align*}
```

On the other hand, it seems to me that flalign aligns it either towards the equality sign, or wildly moves part of the list towards the left of the page.

For a centered array it is straightforward, e.g.:

```
\begin{array}{lrl} ...
```

Is there a similar technique for align or flalign? If not, is array considered the optimal alternative for list of equations as described?

Comment: please always post complete documents, to help test answers and see the issue, but all ams alignments alternate between right and left aligned columns so if you want two left aligned columns use `&a &&=b`

Comment: Thanks. My problem with the solution you suggested is that it seems to create very large spacing between the two columns, whereas I would prefer the list to be quite "tight" like in the align code provided.
I haven't written the document yet, but I think the above code is very representative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMS alignments alternate between right and left aligned columns. You want two left aligned columns, so just leave the right aligned columns blank.

As far as I understand the question you want

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\text{blablabla} &&= \text{blabla} \\
&\text{bla} &&=  \text{bla}\\
&\text{b} &&=  \text{bla}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!